# How do i find a lost element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Well I have the problem, I can't log out when i just log in (without reloading the page).
And I cant log in when I just logged out (again with page reload it works).
Well I think after reloading the nav, he forgets the id of logout or something?

```
<script>

    logout = $('#logout')
    loginform = $('#loginform')

    logout.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'accounts/logout/',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json)
                });
            },
        });
    });

    loginform.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        login();
    });

    function login() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'accounts/login/',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json)
                /* Reloades the navbar */
                $('#usergui').load(document.URL + ' #usergui');
            }
        });
    }
    ;
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="usergui">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a id="logout"> </span>
                Logout
        </a></li> 
        {% else%}
        <li><a> </span>
                Login
        </a></li>
        <li><a> </span>
                Register
        </a></li> 
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

After Login my user gets authenticated and reloading the nav make only logout appear.
The Element wasn't created dynamicaly-> it's static

Comment: Are you manipulating DOM elements?

Comment: if reloading the navbar counts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are reloading the `navbar` the DOM element are removed and so does there event handler

You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach

```
$(document).on('click', '#logout', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'accounts/logout/',
        success : function(json) {
            console.log(json)
            });
        },
    });
});

$(document).on('submit', '#loginform', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    login();
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "re-add" the onclick event handler to the logout tag after this code executes `$('#usergui').load(document.URL + ' #usergui');`.

Your script should look something like this:

```
<script>
function doButtonHandlers(){
    logout = $('#logout');
    loginform = $('#loginform');

    logout.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'accounts/logout/',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                });
            },
        });
    });

    loginform.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        login();
    });
}

function login() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'accounts/login/',
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json)
            /* Reloades the navbar */
            $('#usergui').load(document.URL + ' #usergui');
            doButtonHandlers();
        }
    });
};

doButtonHandlers();
```